# Route exists but an ajax request never reaches it -- "not round"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

**rake routes** confirms that a route exists:

```
    control1_route1 DELETE /control1/route1(.:format)
```

But when I send a "delete" request to it:

```
  var url = "<%= control1_route1_url %>";
  $.ajax({url: url, type: "DELETE"}).
    done(function(data) {
      alert("ok");
    });
```

it never reaches it and returns 404. Why is that?

And:

```
  # controller
  def route1
  end

  # routes
  delete "control1/route1" => "control1#route1"
```

Comment: Have you tried `url: "control1/route1"` (without the trailing slash)?

Comment: What's in the Rails server after doing the request? What's in the browser console tab Network?

Comment: `type` is for specifying the format (as in HTML or JSON) - not the http method. So this creates a GET request with a `Content-Type="DELETE"` header.

Answer (score 1):

This part is incorrect: `$.ajax({url: url, type: "DELETE"})`

Change `type` to `method` `$.ajax({url: url, method: "DELETE"})`

According to the [jQuery AJAX docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you have to use `method` to configure the HTTP method for the AJAX call.

That should correctly reach your route.